# pushVIewController causing dismiss to not work, present removes nav bar

Tags: swift

In my app I go from my Initial View Controller to View Controller 2. In a few places, on the main way to do this I do

```
      if let addVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ADD_CARD_STORYBOARD_IDENTIFIER) as? AddCardViewController {
        let addNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addVC)
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
          self.splitViewController?.present(addNavigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
          self.present(addNavigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
      }
```

I was having issues with some things working on iPad and somethings working on iPhone and not the other way around.

On View Controller 2 when I have done what I need to do I use

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works perfectly.

However, the user can also tap a button VC 1 which brings up a UIAlertController

From the UIAlertController I can go to the 2nd VC. However on that I am not doing present(... I am doing

```
if let addCardVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ADD_CARD_STORYBOARD_IDENTIFIER) as? AddCardViewController {
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addCardVC, animated: true)
}
```

This is where my problem is. If I do the push and then try to dismiss on the 2nd VC nothing happens.

I tried to do present here, but when I did the 2nd VC lost the Navigation Bar.

Is there anyway I can do the present AND keep the nav bar, or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. I was not using

```
 let addNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addVC)
```

I was just trying to say

```
if let addCardVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ADD_CARD_STORYBOARD_IDENTIFIER) as? AddCardViewController {
  self.navigationController?.present(addCardVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

when I needed to say

```
if let addCardVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ADD_CARD_STORYBOARD_IDENTIFIER) as? AddCardViewController {
let addNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addCardVC)
self.navigationController?.present(addNavigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really now if I understand well, but it seems that you have two ways to go to VC2, through VC1 or UIAlertController.

I would recommend you to create a protocol and implement it in your VC1, so you can pass it to your UIAlertController (if you have a custom UIAlertController). After dismissing your UIAlertController, you would call the delegate method implemented by VC1 and then it would be responsible to push the view controller. For example:

Protocol

```
protocol VCDelegate {
    pushToVC2()
}
```

VC1 class:

```
class VC1: UIViewController, VCDelegate {

    //...       

    let customAlertVC = CustomAlertViewController() // Declaring your custom alert view controller

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customAlertVC.delegate = self // Set its delegate
    } 

    func pushToVC2(){ // implementing method to go to VC2
        self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ADD_CARD_STORYBOARD_IDENTIFIER) as? AddCardViewController {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addCardVC, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

Custom UIAlertViewController:

```
class CustomAlertViewController: AlertViewController {

     // delegate to call the implemented method in VC1
     var delegate: VCDelegate?

     //...

     func didTapButton(){
         self.dismiss(animated: false) {
             delegate.pushToVC2() // called on dismiss completion
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: the PushViewController is the problem. I cannot use Push because I am unable to dismiss . I want to present, but presenting from the Alert removes the nav bar